# Как сохранить действие нажатие кнопки True или False при изменении ориентации телефона?

Tags: java, android, button

У меня есть приложение с TextView (в котором поочередно появляются вопросы из массива данных) и 3 кнопки True, False и Next (они отвечают за ответ на вопросы и кнопка Next за показ следующего вопроса). Мне нужно что бы кнопки True и False при нажатии на одну из них и при смене ориентации телефона оставались такими же не активными.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;
private Button mNextButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;
private Button mCheatButton;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT = 0;


private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[]{
        new Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),


@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");



@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");



@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
}


private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
private boolean mIsCheater;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
    }


    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);


    mCheatButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
    mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
            Intent intent = CheatActivity.newIntent(MainActivity.this, answerIsTrue);

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT);
        }
    });
    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(true);

        }
    });

    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            mIsCheater = false;

            updateQuestion();

        }


        private void updateQuestion(){
            int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
            mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
            mFalseButton.setEnabled(true);
            mTrueButton.setEnabled(true);
        }


    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK){
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT){
        if (data == null){
            return;
        }
        mIsCheater = CheatActivity.wasAnswerShown(data);
    }
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
    mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);
    mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);

    int messageResId = 0;
    if (mIsCheater){
        messageResId = R.string.judgment_toast;
    }else {

    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
        messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;

    }
    else
        {
        messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При повороте экрана в андроиде активность разрушается и создается снова. Чтобы восстановить исходное состояние нужно использовать методы `onSaveInstanceState()` и `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Примерно так:

```
   @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("mFalseButton", mFalseButton.isEnabled());
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("mTrueButton", mTrueButton.isEnabled());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mFalseButton.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mFalseButton"));
        mTrueButton.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mTrueButton"));
    }
```

Comment: Наверно имелось виду isEnabled вместо getState

Comment: @AntonKnyazev да, пожалуй :)